# React Google Charts Candlestick colors and wicks not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, candlestick-chart, react-google-charts

I am trying to implement the React Google Charts candlestick charts, and I am plugging in my own data into the charts but when the charts are displayed, the candlesticks are all being displayed in one color at a time even when I change the color options.

```
options={{
        legend: "none",
        bar: { groupWidth: "100%" }, // Remove space between bars.
        candlestick: {
          fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: "#a52714" }, // red
          risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: "#0f9d58" } // green
        }
      }}
```

I am almost certain my data is shaped correctly (this is the ordered_data array of arrays passed to the charts data property.

```
  data={this.state.ordered_data}
```

The wicks are also not displaying on the charts even though my data fits into the same shape as the default example data.

I am linking to a codesandbox showing my charts.

The chart without any wicks and with all candles with the same color looks as shown below
[image]

The codesandbox with the code for the chart is embedded below. Here's the official example for using this chart: [React Google Charts candlestick](https://react-google-charts.com/candleStick-chart). I've tried to customize the colors using the options fallingColor and risingColor settings to no avail. How can I get the wicks to display?

You can view the shape of my data from the console in the codesandbox.

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-oskar-15lkf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark" style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;" title="charming-oskar-15lkf" allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
  sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at the code sandbox and the data in the console,
it looks as though your data is structured as follows...

```
"day", "open", "high", "low", "close"
```

but according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#data-format) for Google's Candlestick Chart,
the data **should be** structured as follows...

```
"day", "low", "open", "close", "high"
```